# Navigationbar buttons move for a few seconds during device orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

In my navigationbar I have a leftbarbuttonitem and a rightbarbuttonitem. While doing device orientation those barbutton items are coming towards the title view for a few seconds and after that going back to end positions. Any solution for this repositioning. 
Thanks in advance.

```
UIBarButtonItem *btLeftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segNav];
[segNav release];

UIBarButtonItem *btRightItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segRight];
[segRight release];

//segNav and segRight are UISegmentedControl objects

navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
[navItem setRightBarButtonItem:btRightItem]; //set left button for navigation item
[navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:btLeftItem];   //set right button for navigation item

[navItem setTitleView:titleLab]; //set navigation item title view
```

Comment: Can you please share the code ??. otherwise it is very difficult to solve the problem